# chef client failed to read machine metadata

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a few servers installed with chef. 
one of them started to fail when running

```
sudo chef-client -j /etc/chef/first-boot.json
```

ONLY on one of the machines

when debugging, the error is

```
Re-raising exception: NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The trace is

```
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/data_collector/messages/helpers.rb:133:in `read_node_uuid'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/data_collector/messages/helpers.rb:111:in `node_uuid'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/data_collector/messages.rb:40:in `run_start_message'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/data_collector.rb:130:in `block in run_started'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/data_collector.rb:307:in `disable_reporter_on_error'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/data_collector.rb:128:in `run_started'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/event_dispatch/dispatcher.rb:43:in `call'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/event_dispatch/dispatcher.rb:43:in `block in call_subscribers'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/event_dispatch/dispatcher.rb:34:in `each'
  /opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/chef-12.18.31/lib/chef/event_dispatch/dispatcher.rb:34:in `call_subscribers'
```

The line is

```
metadata["node_uuid"]
```

The metadata is coming by reading `data_collector_metadata.json` file

```
    def metadata
              Chef::JSONCompat.parse(Chef::FileCache.load(metadata_filename))
   rescue Chef::Exceptions::FileNotFound
          {}
 end
```

I'm struggling with this ... why is this working on some servers and on this it does not

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was the issue. 
The difference was the chef-client version 
the Startup script reinstalls chef with the latest version. 
Using this bash

```
curl -L "https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh" | bash
```

I've modified to a version specific bash

```
curl -LO https://omnitruck.chef.io/install.sh && sudo bash ./install.sh -v 12.15.19 && rm install.sh
```

And it worked

Comment: You should be aware that 12.0.2 is super duper outdated and you should really fix this ASAP :) Test Kitchen is a good way to try new versions of Chef to make sure they work for you.